# Force Playwright to fail in case of typescript errors

Tags: typescript, e2e-testing, playwright

I can't find a way to force Playwright to fail if spec.ts file has typescript issues, like missing members of the interface. It there any way to do it?

Comment: You could run tsc with noEmit always before you run your tests.

Comment: This sounds like you would just want it to fail compilation on the TypeScript side of things then, no?

Comment: @DavidR yes, that's the plan :)

Comment: @Azargoth Cool :) The TypeScript shouldn’t compile if there are compile time errors. Are you running into runtime issues? TypeScript features like interfaces are only checked at time of compile, not at runtime.

Comment: @Azargoth were you able to do this without having a separate compilation before running the tests?

Comment: @jbojcic nope, no success so far. I'm assuming creating separate tsconfig.json with noEmit flag is not a success.